# Are cake themes within plugins possible?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have mobile theme in /View/Themed/Mobile/

I also have a plugin that I'd like to build a mobile them for as well.  I've put the plugin themed designs here: /View/Themed/Mobile/Plugin/Myplugin/ControllerName/add.ctp

Cake is still using the native theme.  Is it possible to even do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, themes and plugin work.

A simple (but cheaty) way to find where cake is looking for your view Files is by *temporarily* putting `debug($path . $name . $ext)` immediately before [this line](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/View/View.php#L1004).

Doing so you'll see something like this:

```
'app/View/Themed/MyTheme/Plugin/MyPlugin/ControllerName/index.ctp'
'app/View/Themed/MyTheme/ControllerName/index.ctp'
'app/View/Plugin/MyPlugin/ControllerName/index.ctp'
'app/Plugin/MyPlugin/View/ControllerName/index.ctp'
'app/View/ControllerName/index.ctp'
'lib/Cake/View/ControllerName/index.ctp'
...
```

As you can see, cake checks for a plugin-specific theme view, a theme view, and then the standard permutations.

The path in the question appears to be correct - which probably indicates an overlooked typo in the file path. Using the above technique you can copy and paste the path into your editor and ensure you create the file exactly where cake is looking for it.

Comment: thumbs up for the cheaty way :)